# db.collection.find({$text :{$search : "some text"}}) is not returning anything

Tags: database, mongodb, text, mongodb-query

I have a mongo database collection with name shopping here

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5fcbaddafac0e534d086696c"},
"imagePath":"https://5.imimg.com/data5/UU/DQ/MY-54426657/tata-salt-packet-500x500.png",
"title":"Tata salt packet",
"description":"used for making food!!",
"price":10,"__v":0
}
```

when i try to search the title in the collection with the command

```
db.shopping.find({$text :{$search : "Tata salt packet"}})
```

nothing is comming in the output it just exits and waits for the next command

i already done indexing by this command

```
db.shopping.createIndex( { title: "text" } )
```

and got this as output

```
{
        "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "note" : "all indexes already exist",
        "ok" : 1
}
```

can anyone tell me whats the problem why i am not getting the output
here is how it looks
[image]

thanks

Comment: you can do this much faster and better Atlas Search. This $text exact match is not as good as Atlas Search. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search

Comment: Oh okay, thank you so much for the link <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try Exact Phrase like below,

```
db.shopping.find( { $text: { $search: "\"Tata salt packet\"" } } );
```

Comment: no it's not working,it still doesn't give the output

Comment: Can you share the result of the following query?
db.shopping.getIndexes({})

Comment: sure here it is

Comment: I have the same index info and It is working fine.
[
 {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_"
 },
 {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "_fts" : "text",
   "_ftsx" : 1
  },
  "name" : "description_text",
  "weights" : {
   "description" : 1
  },
  "default_language" : "english",
  "language_override" : "language",
  "textIndexVersion" : 3
 }
]

what's your mongo db version ?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.4.2

Comment: thanks this worked after i reinstalled the mongodb may be some issue with my laptop but its fine now thanks :)